# Which two oil platforms might Vietnam use in its propaganda posters? And why?

Tags: propaganda, vietnam

In Vung Tau, in the south of Vietnam, one can find a propaganda poster (see this picture of 7 November 2017 and further information about the picture: [at Wikimedia Commons](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Vietnamese_propaganda_poster_near_the_pilgrimage_site_Christ_the_King_in_Vung_Tau;_featuring_oil_platforms,_a_sailor_with_a_gun_and_the_front_of_a_red_ship_(7_November_2017,_16;54PM).jpg#.7B.7Bint:filedesc.7D.7D))

The poster featurs oil platforms, a sailor with a gun and the front of a red ship.

The text in the sky, above the two oil platforms presumably reads (can not verify accents at this resolution):

> Tất cả vì biển đảo quê hương, vì biên cương Tổ quốc!

Which is probably just a general propaganda slogan, not specifically related to the oil platforms. What interests me most though, is the oil platforms. I am wondering if anyone might know which two oil platforms they might be, and why might they be used in a propaganda poster?

At the right side of the white shape of Vietnam (featured on the red ship), there seem to have been two white pieces of text, presumably indicating the geographical location of the two oil platforms (one located along the height of the center of Vietnam, the other one at the height of the far south of the country).

I have a further picture of the red ship here, but unfortunately the resolution of the camera wasn't good enough to make the text very legible. That's why I would like to ask for your help.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Bạch Hổ oil field is offshore from Vũng Tàu, and is politically significant; it was discovered just after the fall of Saigon.

The map may be showing the Spratly Islands (in the south) and the Paracel Islands (in the North), not oil fields. These are islands that are disputed between Vietnam, PRC, RoC, Malaysia and the Philippines. "The Spratly Islands are important for economic and strategic reasons. The Spratly area holds potentially significant, but largely unexplored, reserves of oil and natural gas" (wikipedia)